# CentOS on VM Virtual Box can't find the network

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox

I've installed CentOS, Minimal version, using Oracle VM Virtual Box.  I need to install some things, but when I run yum, it reports

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?
     release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
```

The URL is valid, and anyway, ping can't find anything.

Network settings show Adapter 1 Attached to: Host-only Adapter, VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter; Promiscuous Mode is Deny, and Cable Connected is checked.

This [StackExchange answer #1 and only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238378/i-have-installed-centos-7-on-virtual-box-but-network-settings-are-missing) suggests using Bridged instead.  I'm trying this, with the default of an Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter, other specs the same (Deny, Cable Connected).  Since ping still can't find anything, I think I must be missing something else I have to tell it.  What can get this box accessing the network?

Comment: Are you on a home or business network? Does your virtual machine have an IP? If so, what is the IP? Can your host get to the Internet?

Comment: I'm on a laptop, currently at home, with Wi-Fi.  The laptop can get to the Internet.  I don't  yet know how to know if the virtual machine has an IP.

Comment: How does your laptop gets it's IP? Is it static or DHCP?

Comment: Static; DHCP is not enabled.

Comment: I suggest you peruse Section 6.7 of the VirtualBox manual section on Networking (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly). It is quite clear from there that a VM with host-only networking cannot talk to the Internet. ~ Some wireless NICs are known to not cope well with bridging. What is the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` when bridging the NIC? Can you ping the VM host or your router?

Comment: I solved the problem, sort of, by switching to VMWare.  Ah, well.  It's working, even if we won't get a neat answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Host-only Adapter. Ok, this one is very wrong. You will not have connectivity with [a host-only adapter](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly):

> ## 6.7. Host-only networking
>
> Host-only networking is another networking mode that was added with
>   version 2.2 of VirtualBox. It can be thought of as a hybrid between
>   the bridged and internal networking modes: as with bridged networking,
>   the virtual machines can talk to each other and the host as if they
>   were connected through a physical Ethernet switch. Similarly, as with
>   internal networking however, a physical networking interface need not
>   be present, **and the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside**
>   the host since they are not connected to a physical networking
>   interface.
>
> Instead, when host-only networking is used, VirtualBox

It's just a matter of READING THE DOCS.

Bridged mode just works without minor tricks on cabled network. See my comments here: [VirtualBox fails to bridge WiFi with guest OS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373059/34720) You will have a lot of aspects to deal with it.

**tl,dr:** Use nat interface.

Answer (score 0):

Given your answers to my clarifying questions, you're not done setting up your guest yet. It will not get an IP address by itself since you do not have any DHCP services, so you will need to give it an IP address.

You will need to use a Bridged or NAT network connection; the IP address you give it will depend in part on what type of network connection you select.

Comment: That would make sense.  Per https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/networking-in-virtualbox-v2, it looks like a NAT network would be fine (as I want to use yum, not have people calling into my VM).  I set this up to support IPv6 not DHCP, but it's not asking me about my IP address, though it does give network CIDR as 10.0.2.0/24 .  So I'm not seeing where to tell it my IP address.  --?  Tx.

Answer (score 0):

The *host-only* network of virtualbox is just that: the guest only has access to the host itself and other VMs sharing the same virtual network.

Quote from https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

> This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface

To be able to connect to the internet from your guest you either must select one of *bridging* or *NAT* modes or you must configure your host to act as a router (which is much more work).

If you are not trying to achieve some special goal I'd recommend using *NAT*, in this mode Virtualbox provides by default a DHCP server too. So you need not configure the network addresses yourself.